# For loop, use past iteration

Tags: procedural-programming

So I'm trying to use Newton's method to find the root of a function. The code works, what isn't working is my absolute error calculation. What I need is to subtract my past iteration from the current one. Unfortunately `#x[n - 1] - x[n]` isn't working for some reason. What can be done?

[image: My code]

Comment: One of the first few things that I see is that your `x[n]` function doesn’t at all depend on n? As well, you are redefining `a`, which is the main argument being used in your `x[n]` function. Also, please edit your question with the code in a code-block, such that other users can copy & paste said code. This is a better method than containing it in an image.

Answer (score 3):

With `x[n_]=...` you define a function (and you redefine it in each iteration). Removing the subscore should help: `x[n]=...` defines a `Downvalue` of `x`. This way, `x` works like a hash table indexed over `n`.

Note that this does *not* define an array in *Mathematica*. Indexing into an array is done with double brackets `[[ ]]` (see documentation of `Part`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to collect your `x[n]` in an object. You then `Abs[Differences[object]]`.

I would strongly urge consideration of alternatives to `For` loops.

There are number of alternatives to `For` loops in Wolfram Language (Mathematica). There are a number of resources on this site, e.g. [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).

These are invaluable resources to consider.

For this case, for example for your function:

```
f[x_] := Exp[x] + 2^(-x) + 2 Cos[x] - 6
```

You could use [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) to implement Newton's method.

```
nm[f_, x_, x0_, n_] := NestList[x - f[x]/f'[x] /. x -> # &, x0, n]
```

You could then play use the output as you wish. For "fun":

```
exam[a_, x_, n_, l_, r_, b_, t_] := 
 Module[{newt = nm[f, x, a, n], im, tab},
  im = Flatten[{Arrow[{{#1, 0}, {#1, f[#1]}}], Red, 
       Arrow[{{#1, f[#1]}, {#2, 0}}]} & @@@ Partition[newt, 2, 1]];
  tab = TableForm[Thread[{Rest@newt, Abs[Differences[newt]]}], 
    TableHeadings -> {Range[n], {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(n\)]\)",
        "|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(n - \
1\)]\)-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(n\)]\)|"}}];
  Table[Column[{Show[Plot[f[x], {x, l, r}], Graphics[im[[1 ;; j]]], 
      PlotRange -> {b, t}, 
      PlotLabel -> Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\) =", a}]], 
     tab}], {j, Length[im]}]]
```

[image]

The image was made using:

```
Export["nme.gif", exam[1.5, x, 4, 1.4, 2, -1, 1], “AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

Comment: +1! Very cool & educational answer. Can you clarify how long it takes to run? That is, I am curious if one can use `Manipulate` with something like this to interactively show students how their initial parameter (educated guess) influences the amount of steps necessary?

Comment: @CATrevillian  you could wrap in Manipulate. There will better ways to code this. I was just appealing to consider alternatives to For. Thank you for feedback.